# Deleted system reserved partition, can't access bios or boot via USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, partitioning, bios

I have 3 disks. Disk 0 has Win10 installation, and a 350MB system reserved partition. Disk 1 had a 100MB system reserved partition that I (mistakenly) believed was from an old Win7 install. I wanted to change Disk 1 to a basic drive so I could use it for backups so I cloned the partition to disk 2 and deleted it from disk 1. Computer now hangs during boot at splash screen that says 'press DEL to enter BIOS'. I press DEL key trying to access BIOS, but system does not react. This occurs even with a Win10 boot USB connected.

Things I've tried:

- Rebooting computer with DEL held from very beginning, also with my hand laid across keyboard pressing a dozen keys.
- Disconnecting Disk 0 allows me to access the BIOS (or boot into the USB, if connected), however this does no good as the Win10 USB will not recognize an OS to repair since it's installed on Disk 0 nor can I change the boot order to place the USB above disk 0. I am also not sure why it does not boot from the USB present by default.
- Changing the boot order anyway, placing USB at highest priority, turning off, connecting disk 0, then rebooting again. Issue persists.

The ultimate goal is to repair my Win10 installation without losing my data on disk 0.

Comment: I don't get why users delete something about which they don't even know. Not just the users but also some bloggers suggest to delete them to free up space. I suggest not to delete Windows RETools partition ever.

Comment: I didn't delete the 100MB system reserved partition on a whim. My OS is Win10, and it was my understanding that Win10 uses a 350MB reserved partition (which is untouched and on disk 0) and that the 100MB reserved partition on Disk1 was a remnant of my old Win7 install. Obviously that line of thinking was incorrect.

Comment: Can't you restore from Disk 2 back to Disk 1? You said you cloned the partition to disk 2.

Comment: How can I do that?